# How to fix the terminal and Linux files for error 20 on a chromebook

Tags: linux, chromebook, google-chrome-os

Today, I was trying to access the terminal and Linux files for Linux, but it suddenly all crashed! I got crosh (press ctrl-alt-t on chrome to get there) to act as my terminal with the code "vsh terminal" and "lxc exec penguin -- /bin/login -f USERNAME", but the actual terminal and Linux files in the files app are not working. When I try to access my Linux files, it gives me an error message that says "Unable to view Linux Files: Error mounting crostini container", and when I open the terminal, it says "[Error starting penguin container: 20 Launching vmshell failed: Error starting crostini for terminal: 20" I have been trying to get this fixed since the morning but was not able to do much. Please tell me how to fix this! My device is an Acer Chromebook. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try `crosh> vmc list`
then

crosh> `vmc start termina`

(termina) chronos@localhost ~ $ `lxc list`

(termina) chronos@localhost ~ $ `logout`

crosh> `vmc container termina penguin`

https://support.google.com/chromebook/thread/78751966?hl=en

Comment: In crosh, I can sign in as my terminal, but in the actual terminal and the Linux files it still gives the error.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the late response, but I fixed it by going to chrome://flags and searching up "Crostini" and change a setting and revert it to the old again (if you don't want a new setting) and restart the computer. This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I've found for this is

[Chrome OS - Crostini fails to start with vmshell error 20](https://gist.github.com/SayantanRC/482656735f24354f0c2de2ba4ba2d0e3#file-chrome-os-crostini-error-20-md)

Checking the `systemctl status cros-sftp` showed errors with that part of the process.

Also, when logging into the root shell via crosh I had problems actually editing config files and using `df` it turns out I'd run out of space on the partition.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer!  I have actually switched to Windows because I was using Linux on a school device, but they shut down the Linux later.